# Can I have 2 routers in a network without bridging

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, nat

My ISP-supplied router is very bad. I have a lot of issues with the NAT rules, NATLOOPBACK, UPNP ...

I will buy another one (**Router 2**). I have to keep the old one connected as a master (**Router 1**).

I don't have the possibility to disable the DHCP of the master.

Can I connect a second router like this?

```
ROUTER 1 (Master)           -->  ROUTER 2 (Slave)            --> COMPUTER 1
IP:192.168.1.1                   IP:192.168.2.1 (static)         IP:192.168.2.2
SUBNET MASK: 255.255.0.0         SUBNET MASK: 255.255.255.0      
DHCP: ENABLED                    DHCP: ENABLED
DHCP RANGE:192.168.1.2~256       DHCP RANGE:192.168.2.2~256
DMZ: 192.168.2.1                 DMZ : (if needed)
FIREWALL: OFF                    FIREWALL: ON
NATLOOPBACK : NO SUPPORT         NATLOOPBACK: YES
UPNP : NO                        UPNP: YES
```

Comment: DHCP is not really part of throughput. I would be inclined to connect  a LAN port on the slave to a LAN port on the Master.  Leave DHCP ON on the master. Turn DHCP OFF on the slave and then all will work fine. Make sure the Slave has a Static IP address on the Master.

Comment: I KNOW you can connect to routers BOTH with DCHP into one another & it to work. They both perform NAT. I'd think it'd work, but not sure if ALL those features would work. For instance how can you DMZ or port-forward w/o access to main router/WAN-modem?

Comment: In the past how I've gotten past this is I ASK the ISP to setup their router/modem in 'bridge mode' so YOUR own desired router gets the WAN IP, port-forwarding, & other things work. You're basically asking for their device to do less things so they're usually cool with it back 10yr ago when I did this for many sites/ISP's

Comment: You can. https://superuser.com/questions/1428402/will-i-be-more-secure-with-my-own-router-behind-my-isps-router/1428415#1428415

Comment: Similar to Gregg's comment: depending on your connection type, you may be able to get a router with the appropriate modem or other interface built in and therefore not need any hardware from your ISP at all. They may even already publish the settings to set your connection up somewhere in their support pages. The usual caveat is that they'll only give you very limited tech support with router problems (or things that look like them).

Comment: Thanks guys. I analyzed your answers. The one of @LawrenceC seems to me very interesting, I will follow it.

Comment: What router is supplied as router 1? Sometimes it is also worth spending some time checking your router supports something like "bridge mode". I have seen this being the case for many consumer-grade routers that did not allow configuring things like its DHCP server.